# Set-based approach to updating multiple tables, rather than a WHILE loop?

Tags: sql-server, xml

Apparently I'm far too used to procedural programming, and I don't know how to handle this with a set-based approach.

I have several temporary tables in SQL Server, each with thousands of records. Some of them have tens of thousands of records each, but they're all part of a record set. I'm basically loading a bunch of xml data that looks like this:

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <id-number>12345678</id-number>
        <col1>blah</col1>
        <col2>heh</col2>
        <more-information>
            <col1>werr</col1>
            <col2>pop</col2>
            <col3>test</col3>
        </more-information>
        <even-more-information>
            <col1>czxn</col1>
            <col2>asd</col2>
            <col3>yyuy</col3>
            <col4>moat</col4>
        </even-more-information>
        <even-more-information>
            <col1>uioi</col1>
            <col2>qwe</col2>
            <col3>rtyu</col3>
            <col4>poiu</col4>
        </even-more-information>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id-number>12345679</id-number>
        <col1>bleh</col1>
        <col2>sup</col2>
        <more-information>
            <col1>rrew</col1>
            <col2>top</col2>
            <col3>nest</col3>
        </more-information>
        <more-information>
            <col1>234k</col1>
            <col2>fftw</col2>
            <col3>west</col3>
        </more-information>
        <even-more-information>
            <col1>asdj</col1>
            <col2>dsa</col2>
            <col3>mnbb</col3>
            <col4>boat</col4>
        </even-more-information>
    </entry>
</root>
```

Here's a brief display of what the temporary tables look like:

**Temporary Table 1 (entry)**:

```
+------------+--------+--------+
|  UniqueID  |  col1  |  col2  |
+------------+--------+--------+
|   732013   |  blah  |  heh   |
|   732014   |  bleh  |  sup   |
+------------+--------+--------+
```

**Temporary Table 2 (more-information)**:

```
+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|  UniqueID  |  col1  |  col2  |  col3  |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|   732013   |  werr  |  pop   |  test  |
|   732014   |  rrew  |  top   |  nest  |
|   732014   |  234k  |  ffw   |  west  |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

**Temporary Table 3 (even-more-information)**:

```
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  UniqueID  |  col1  |  col2  |  col3  |  col4  |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   732013   |  czxn  |  asd   |  yyuy  |  moat  |
|   732013   |  uioi  |  qwe   |  rtyu  |  poiu  |
|   732014   |  asdj  |  dsa   |  mnbb  |  boat  |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I am loading this data from an XML file, and have found that this is the only way I can tell which information belongs to which record, so every single temporary table has the following inserted at the top:

```
T.value('../../id-number[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)') UniqueID,
```

As you can see, each temporary table has a `UniqueID` assigned to it's particular record to indicate that it belongs to the main record. I have a large set of items in the database, and I want to update every single column in each non-temporary table using a set-based approach, but it must be restricted by `UniqueID`.

In tables other than the first one, there is a `Foreign_ID` based on the `PrimaryKey_ID` of the main table, and the `UniqueID` will not be inserted... it's just to help tell what goes where.

Here's the exact logic that I'm trying to figure out:

1. If `id-number` currently exists in the main table, update tables based on the `PrimaryKey_ID` number of the main table, which is the same exact number in every table's `Foreign_ID`. The foreign-key'd tables will have a totally different number than the `id-number` -- they are not the same.
2. If `id-number` does not exist, insert the record. I have done this part.

However, I'm currently stuck in the mind-set that I have to set temporary variables, such as `@IDNumber`, and `@ForeignID`, and then loop through it. Not only am I getting multiple results instead of the current result, but everyone says `WHILE` shouldn't be used, especially for such a large volume of data.

How do I update these tables using a set-based approach?

Comment: So is the XML already extracted into temp tables (i.e. starting with "#") or not?

Comment: Yes it is. #TempTable1, TempTable2, and so on. There's 15 of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have this XML extracted, you could do something similar to:

```sql
UPDATE ent
SET    ent.col1 = tmp1.col1,
       ent.col2 = tmp1.col2
FROM   dbo.[Entry] ent
INNER JOIN #TempEntry tmp1
        ON tmp1.UniqueID = ent.UniqueID;

UPDATE mi
SET    mi.col1 = tmp2.col1,
       mi.col2 = tmp2.col2,
       mi.col3 = tmp2.col3
FROM   dbo.[MoreInformation] mi
INNER JOIN dbo.[Entry] ent -- mapping of Foreign_ID ->UniqueID
        ON ent.PrimaryKey_ID = mi.Foreign_ID
INNER JOIN #TempMoreInfo tmp2
        ON tmp2.UniqueID = ent.UniqueID
       AND tmp2.SomeOtherField = mi.SomeOtherField; -- need 1 more field

UPDATE emi
SET    ent.col1 = tmp3.col1,
       emi.col2 = tmp3.col2,
       emi.col3 = tmp3.col3,
       emi.col4 = tmp3.col4
FROM   dbo.[EvenMoreInformation] emi
INNER JOIN dbo.[Entry] ent -- mapping of Foreign_ID ->UniqueID
        ON ent.PrimaryKey_ID = mi.Foreign_ID
INNER JOIN #TempEvenMoreInfo tmp3
        ON tmp3.UniqueID = ent.UniqueID
       AND tmp3.SomeOtherField = emi.SomeOtherField; -- need 1 more field
```

Now, I should point out that if the goal is truly to

> update every single column in each non-temporary table

then there is a conceptual issue for any sub-tables that have multiple records. If there is no record in that table that will remain the same outside of the `Foreign_ID` field (and I guess the PK of that table?), then how do you know which row is which for the update? Sure, you can find the correct `Foreign_ID` based on the `UniqueID` mapping already in the non-temporary `Entry` table, but there needs to be at least one field that is not an IDENTITY (or `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` populated via `NEWID` or `NEWSEQUENTIALID`) that will be used to find the exact row.

If it is not possible to find a stable, matching field, then you have no choice but to do a wipe-and-replace method instead.

P.S. I used to recommend the `MERGE` command but have since stopped due to learning of all of the bugs and issues with it. The "nicer" syntax is just not worth the potential problems. For more info, please see [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Comment: I know which row is which based on the Foreign_ID of every table. It will always match the `PrimaryKey_ID` of the first table. The entry table has a `PrimaryKey_ID`, and all additional tables have a `Foreign_ID` key that is the same number.

Comment: @heh Please read my answer again ;-). Your sample data shows, for the `more-information` table, two entries with a `UniqueID` of **732014**. How do you know which of those 2 rows is to update which row in the non-temporary table (assuming you update all but the PK and `Foreign_ID` fields)? Without another field to narrow down to a single row, both existing rows will be updated to one of those two rows in the temporary table. Does that make more sense now?

Comment: Oh yeah. That is doing a `../../id-number[1]` search in XML. Meaning each record is going to have that unique number. So here's what I want to do: if that temporary table number exists in the main table, `Entry`, then find the `PrimaryKey_ID` of that particular record, and match it based on the `Foreign_ID` of the other tables. Does that make sense?

Comment: @heh You are not understanding the issue here. I have already accounted for mapping `id-number` -> `PrimaryKey_ID` -> `Foreign_ID`. That is not the issue. Look at your sample data more closely, specifically the first `<entry>` element. It has two `<even-more-information>` elements in it and they both share the same `id-number`. When updating rows in databases, you need to match the PK field (or some set of unique fields).

Comment: Sorry. If I'm understanding you correctly, they'll have the same ID number, right? That <even-more-information> is just a record. Two of them mean they are two records, which are then mapped. This means when I use `SELECT * FROM [even-more-information] INNER JOIN [entry] ON [even-more-information].[Foreign_ID] = [entry].[PrimaryKey_ID]`, it will return multiple results for a single entry. The `Primary Key` is different for each record; `Foreign_ID` is a `BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1)`, it is not a primary key. Does that make sense, or am I still confused?

Comment: @heh It sounds like you are still confused, at least at the end. Yes, two `<even-more-information>` elements in the XML for the same `<entry>` record refer to two rows in the `EvenMoreInformation` table with the same `ForeignID`. So yes, that query, will return 2 rows for that particular `[entry].[PrimaryKey_ID]`. THAT is the problem. You have what should be two rows in the XML that should each update a single row in the real table yet they will both update both rows since you are not giving enough info to narrow down to update a single row per individual element in the XML.

Comment: If possible, should I just delete all the records in a certain table when matched by that `Foreign_ID`? I can then reinsert them while attached, if that would work. If not, how would you go about fixing this conceptual problem?

Comment: @heh Yes, that is what I have been saying and is the recommendation in my answer: if you do not have any field in the XML (outside of the `id-number` / `UniqueID`) that is NOT changing for one of the related tables, then you have no choice but to DELETE and INSERT (i.e. wipe-and-replace) since there is no way to do an UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `MERGE` which does upsert ( update and insert ) in a single statement

First merge entries to the main table

For other tables, you can do a join with main table to get foreign id mapping

```
MERGE Table2 as Dest
USING ( select t2.*, m.primaryKey-Id as foreign_ID
        from #tempTable2 t2 
        join mainTable m 
        on t2.id-number = m.id-number 
        ) as Source
on Dest.Foreign_ID = m.foreign_ID
WHEN MATCHED
   THEN Update SET Dest.COL1 = Source.Col1
WHEN NOT MATCHED then
   INSERT (FOREGIN_ID, col1, col2,...)
  values ( src.foreign_Id, src.col1, src.col2....)
```

Comment: You don't need to create a separate mapping table as it already exists in the form of the main "Entry" table.